# What does RaspberryPi OS does different than Ubuntu when mounting a drive that could explain activity on mount

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive, mount

I've just installed two Seagate Ironwulf NAS harddisks of 4 TB in an Icy Box enclosure, Raid 1 set-up. I've setup a single partition using parted, and set up an ext4 filesystem. It's connected to a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspberry Pi OS 10.

As soon as I mount the drive/partition, I hear the drive spin up as expected, and then a sound like a heartbeat can be heard - like the head is moving two times per second. [Here's a recording of the sound.](https://tinyurl.com/yy2gwghs)

This happens both when mounting manually via `sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/IcyBox` and when automounting. This 'heartbeat' stops as soon as I unmount the drive. It seems I can successfully write to the drive - the heartbeat continues.

Now, since I'm just mounting the drive, and no programme supposedly is using it, is there a way to find out why the drive is spinning?

And, more importantly: this doesn't happen when I mount the same drive on my Ubuntu (18.04.5) laptop. **How does Raspberry PI OS handle mounted drives differently than Ubuntu**, which could explain this difference in disk activity when mounting?

Comment: You need to add more info from logs.

Comment: One simple check could be to install `lsof` and check if there's any file opened

Comment: Does the enclosure have its own power?

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.
@MatsK, which logs should I add? What level? From which timeframe (I assume when mounting)?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, I'll try that when I have the opportunity.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, it does, so it's not a power issue.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bug / quirk in the usb driver - if you look at the output from the `top` command you will see the driver virtually consistently at the top.

I've been trying to sort the none raid ICY BOX drives I have (even had a bounty running) but to no avail.  It seems fine on x86 boxes but not ARM.  No matter what settings or ext versions I tried it just glitches.  See [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/115887/the-usb-storage-driver-seems-to-be-constantly-accessing-external-usb-drive-on-a)

Checking the manufacturers web site the chips are not spec'd for LINUX in my boxes - I guess it's the same on the RAID versions.

I find this happens with no files on the drive by the way.

Comment: Shit, only seeing this now. Thank you for chipping in. I tried the `top` command and found `systemd` highly ranked all the time. Is that the driver you are are talking about? (sorry, I'm new to this stuff). Where exactly is the chip info listed? The product page on Raidsonic's website doesn't list that as far as I can see: https://www.raidsonic.de/products/external_cases/soho_raid/index_en.php?we_objectID=3590

Comment: I use `lsusb` (possibly with sudo) and tracked down the chip set from that.  The linked page has *Windows >7, MAC OS X >10.5* as O/S

Comment: Ah, I will see if I can track back the chip set also (though it's likely the same as your device). That linked page isn't strictly correct, given it works correctly with my Ubuntu laptop. Thanks - will update if I hear more from Raidsonic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no real difference in the mounting between the raspberry pi's OS and your standard Ubuntu. It is likely that there is a process holding your disk. Use

```
lsof +f -- /dev/sda1
```

or

```
fuser -m /dev/sda1
```

to find out which process that might be. There are a number of processes that may be using your hard drive, but it depends a bit on what you installed. Here's a list I encountered (both on pi and other Linuces):

- NFS
- kjournald
- updatedb

But there may be others.

However, if you can unmount the drive, there should not be a process holding your drive.

Also, ext4 accesses the drive from time to time; going back to ext2 will reduce the access (but you loose journaling). Adding `noatime,nodiratime,commit=60` as mount-options may also reduce the accesses. This would be  the same as on a non-pi OS, however.